# Using Cudaprofiler on Windows

Tags: profiling, cuda

I am trying to profile my program for gauging the performance .I start the visual profiler ..make a new project. Then I select the myprogram.exe for the launch option and workspace is set to the direcotry which contains this .exe file.Arguments=--noprompt and max execution time is set to 3000.
Now when I run the profiler it makes 3 passes which says program run completed but then shows up 
"Error in reading profiler output."

Any hints to make this thing work correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the current versions of both the  toolkit and driver installed, the [current version](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/cuda_3_2_downloads.html) is 3.2. Also make sure that you're getting the Visual Profiler from the correct location.

Incidentally, you mention using "--noprompt" which may mean you're using cutil, I'd advise against that. NVIDIA use it to simplify the SDK samples but it's not ideal, in particular in the way it checks for errors.

Comment: I have the previous versions( 2.2) .Point is I dont want to upgrade now since I have some code working.Also some of the standard examples too done work with the profiler.